# Laptop's battery time drastically decreased

Tags: laptop, battery, battery-life

First up, I hope I posted this on the right forum, as I don't think it's a software issue.

A few days ago, I bought a refurbished ThinkPad T420s. The first day, it had a battery capacity of roughly one hour and fourty-five minutes. However, after taking it to school, watching some videos on it and playing some games on it, the next day the battery lasted **15 minutes**. That's an enormous decrease in just one day. So, does anyone know why this happened, how I can potentially fix this and avoid it in the future? I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.3.

Thank you,
Thijs365

PS: I'm sorry if this question (or a simular question) already exists.

EDIT: Power statistics shows that there's only 3.7 Wh from the initial 44  Wh left. Unfortunatly, I didn't run it before this incident occurred.

EDIT #1: When taking it to school, the laptop (and therefor the accu) is exposed to cold weather. I know, that doesn't have a very good impact on the accu.

Comment: Have you put the device through a few charge cycles and does it still exhibit the same behavior? Then the most likely cause is a defective battery. In some cases "refurbished" laptops of that age do not include a new battery or include very cheap off-brand batteries. This device is 6 years old, it might just need a new battery. Otherwise, there is no way to explain the behavior you have seen with the information given.

Comment: Yes, with a battery life that short, it's unavoidable to not put it through a few power cycles. The battery in it is a Lenovo battery, and it performed well for the price I've paid for it, until now. Still, how can a battery lose 1 hour and 30 minutes of time in just one day?

Comment: There are lots of things that affect battery run time.  However, if you got 1:45 one day and 0:15 the next day, I would bet that the battery simply didn't recharge more than a small amount.  There are lots or reasons why that could happen, but I would start with that assumption and initially focus on ruling out things that could have caused it.

Comment: What options can I eluminate?

Answer (score 1):

It may not be a problem with the battery at all.

I had a similar problem a couple of years ago. This is what I did.

Take the battery out and just check for dust accumulation on it.

Next, without the battery inserted, press down on the power button of the laptop for something like 90 to 100 seconds.

If the problem is due to capacitors in the input ports for the battery, this should allow the capacitors to drain all excess charges and give you back a good, clean laptop.

Also, if it's possible, check the voltage across the battery and see if it's normal. If it isn't, well, it's definitely a problem with the battery and you might have to replace it.

Comment: I just followed your guide, and I assume that when you say: "remove the battery", I also have to remove the charger?

Also, I checked for dust but I couldn't find any. While using it without battery, I did take the battery out once or twice. I didn't check for the voltage, however.

I did give you an upvote, as I'm sure this is going to be very helpful for other people who find themselves in the same situation. For me, however, it didn't work (yet).

Comment: Yes, disconnect the battery and the charger, leave the computer off and hold down on the power button.

Comment: Too bad it didn't work. Did you try finding the voltage across the battery? Also, try finding the resistance. You can do this with a standard multimeter you get in a local hardware store.

Comment: I'll pick one up, and get the voltage. Also, I can calculate the resistance by doing R=U/I, right?

Comment: You could, but multimeters have an ohm meter in them. That will give a direct reading of the resistance